# using Gcs match glob parameter for fetching specific files under a subdirectory in python

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, glob

I'm trying fetching specific files from given bucket:

```
my_bucket
  dirA
    dirX
      file1.json
      file2.json
      file1.csv

    dirY
      file2.csv

  dirZ
    dirX
      file3.json
      file3.csv
```

Using python's sdk "match_glob" parameter, I'd like to fetch only the files which is conform to the `**/dirX/**.json` pattern.

Ie: I'd like to get the
`dirA/dirX/file1.json`, `dirA/dirX/file2.json` & `dirZ/dirX/file3.json` files.

Trying the `**/dirX/**.json` pattern yielded empty result.

What is wrong with that pattern?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using  this pattern `**/*.json` instead of  `**/dirX/**.json` as it will return the empty results because dirX is not a directory on the root of the bucket, but rather a subdirectory of both dirA and dirZ.

You can use the match_glob parameter like `**/*.json`, this pattern will fetch all .json files in the dirX subdirectory of any directory in the bucket.

When the matchGlob query parameter is set to a glob pattern, the objects list operation only returns objects that match the glob pattern in items[]. You can check this [List objects and prefixes using glob](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list#list-objects-and-prefixes-using-glob)